# Detect beacon without using app Radbeacon?

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, altbeacon, beacon

I have a situation where I want my users to install my app for which I am using beacons. So the phone should detect the presence of app without an app, I have found a [link](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/07/22/how-to-push-messages-without-an-app.html) which says it is possible in iOS because google has build beacon detector in chrome app but is there a way by which it works for android as well?
Any direction given will be highly appreciate.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want an iPhone to detect your iBacon with out the app registered to for this iBeacon installed. This is not possible on iOS.

Comment: @rckoenes what about the android OS??

Comment: I have not experience with Android.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Chrome app has support for detecting Eddystone-URL beacon frames on both iOS and Android.  I am the one who wrote the ["How To Push Beacon Messages Without an App" post](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/07/22/how-to-push-messages-without-an-app.html) you link to in your question.  At the time that post was written, Google had only released the functionality for the Chrome app for iOS.   Since then they have released similar functionality for Chrome for Android.

The details of how the user opts-in to beacon notifications on Chrome is a bit different for Android.

In addition to Chrome support for Eddystone-URL, Android also supports beacon notifications through its Google Nearby service as part of Google Play Services, if they are installed on the phone.  (On most US and European phones Google Play Services is installed.  On most Chinese phones it is not.)  Using this system, you must first register the beacons with Google (it works with iBeacon, Eddystone frames, and AltBeacon), but the notification to be displayed must be configured on Google servers.  You can read more about this [here.](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview)